# Raspberry Pi shutdowns and restarts in abnormal way

Tags: raspbian, software-installation

When i try to install python imaging Library using
cmd: sudo pip install --upgrade Pillow,
cpu usage goes above 99% and my pi Shutdowns suddenly and restarts again, so i am unable to install library, how to resolve the issue i am using raspbian jessie os.

Comment: The model of Pi and how you are powering it would be useful to know.

Comment: I am using Raspberry pi-3 model & using 5v normal charger, there was no issues till now only when installing Pillow this happens.

Comment: while installing cpu processing % becomes high and it reboots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Get a better power supply.  It is not supplying enough power when the Pi is busy which is causing the reboot.
2. What is this fixation with pip about with Python programmers?  You should always use the packages provided in the repositories as they will have been tested to be compatible with the rest of the system.  Try `sudo apt-get install python-pil python3-pil`

Comment: The [raspberrypi.org docs](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/software/python.md) do recommend pip over apt-get for more recently updated packages: 'Not all Python packages are available in the Raspbian archives, and those that are can sometimes be out-of-date. If you can't find a suitable version in the Raspbian archives, you can install packages from the Python Package Index (PyPI).'

Comment: @goobering Even though the advice may be accurate I still think it is bad advice from raspberrypi.org.  It seems to lead to broken installs.

Comment: @joan thanks  for your advice i have solved it by changing to better power supply

Comment: While I understand your rationale for 2) using `pip` is not only recommended by raspberrypi.org but is essentialy the default advice in all books and tutorials (the *pythonic* way) - which is why people will think of this first most of the time. But you're right going for the repository will usually result in working system.